# Org referencing title on #+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have the following Org files:

*main.org*

```
#+TITLE: Main Document - Draft
#+SETUPFILE: ../themes/main-theme/main-theme.setup

* Test 1
```

*main-theme.setup* (CSS already loads correctly for HTML exports).

```
# -*- mode: org; -*-

#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../themes/report-theme/css/gutenberg.min.css"/>
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <img src="../themes/main-theme/imgs/logo.png" /> {{{title}}} [[title]] [[:title]] [:title] {{{:title}}} ‘{{{title}}}’  ‘{{{title}}}’
```

How do I reference the `TITLE` parameter in `HTML_HEAD_EXTRA`?

Comment: If at all possible, it would be `{{{title}}}` - evaluate `(info "(org) Macro Replacement")` for more info.

Comment: I updated the header on the original question, none of those combinations have been working unfortunately.